# Deploying a JAVA project to client

Tags: java

I'm currently working on a project on Java Applet, Frames and now i have to deploy it. But the problem is this how can i hide the source code of the project? I've to deploy it to a local user on Windows OS. How can i make the .exe of the code?

Comment: Check out [this post](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-to-exe.html).

Comment: When you say "Java Applet, Frames" do you mean that your project runs in a web browser?  In that case, your client's web browser will need to have a Java plug-in installed, and you will need to distribute your application with an HTML file that the client opens.  Bala R's link has some good suggestions, but they all assume that you are already building your project as a desktop application, not an applet.

Comment: have you considered searching for "java exe" using the search box on the upper right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert my java program to an .exe file ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file)

Comment: You distribute the .class files, not the .java source files. Obviously not the plain .class files, but wrapped in a .jar which can optionally be wrapped in a .exe as has been pointed out to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options you have.

**If you just want to wrap the Java code in an executable file** that works in Windows. You have:

- [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/)
- [JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/)

Both are good.

**If you want to wrap as a service** so that you can perform `myapp.bat {install|start|stop}`, you have

- [Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp)

**If you just want to have a couple of bat/shell scripts auto generated at the build time** that will launch your app on double clicking. You may look into Maven, there is a good Maven plugin called *AppAssembler*

- [Maven AppAssembler Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/)

Comment: Note:  JSmooth is nice but has not been updated since 2007.

Answer (score 1):

The best tool for building **.exe** is [**InstallJammer**](http://www.installjammer.com/)

It also provides wizard type installation with all options.

Comment: Why is it better than launch4j or jsmooth?

Comment: It's easy as well as for an instance take an example that if we want to create an exe that contains postgreSQL database, JRE and Web application. So i've tried in JSmooth and it was not making it properly and InstallJammer made it easily.

Comment: Interesting! But from its forum, Windows 7's embedded shortcut is not properly implemented yet for `AppUserModelID` support. So, it may have several issues like pinning the app's shortcut to Windows 7's taskbar and application security http://www.installjammer.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1362&p=7316&hilit=win7#p7316

Comment: i'd used the above tool "InstallJammer" but it doesn't create .exe of the class file.
it just packages all .class files into a single .exe and that .exe extracts all the .class files at the client's local directory.